# Excel Row() and Column() Function

Tags: excel, function, row, excel-formula

I have a simple question:

How do I reference a row combined with a column or vice versa? 
e.g.
I have a table like this:

```
  |A|B|C|D|
1 |1|0|1|
2 |4|4|2|
3 |7|2|3|
4 |5|7|2|
5 |3|9|1|
```

To reference A1, how do I reference it using the Row() function
        
I want the column to remain a constant but the row be varaible according to which row I am on.

If I am on D5, for instance, I want something like: `=SUM(ARow(), CRow())` which is equivalent to `=SUM(A5, C5)` which returns 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Sorry For the previous answer, given you want to change row but keep column constant, you could use the `$` reference in the formula.

For example, if your formula in D5 was:

```
= Sum($A5, $C5)
```

That would keep the column constant and the row would change.

Similarly, `$A$5` would force the formula to ALWAYS use `A5` and `A$5` would force the formula to always use row 5, but change the column.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: John, the question was about a worksheet function to do this. you are showing VBA code.

Comment: :) - Sorry - forgot the tags in the question

Comment: furthermore i'm not referring to the Row() property... Could you please remove the answer and post a new one more related to the question if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

the `ROW()` and `COLUMN()` function reference rows and columns, not single cells...
You might be helped with the `ADDRESS()` function, where you can use row and column numbers as parameters.

And to the basics to reference a column-row combination without explaining further on the logic of your function you could simply use the cell address itself:

D5 : `=SUM(A5, C5)`